# click function not working on document.getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript, click

I have below code

```
<div class="test">Click Me</div>
<script>
document.getElementsByClassName('test').addEventListener('click', function(){
  alert('Hello world');
}, false);
```

Alert is not triggering. JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ssod54fh/

Comment: Let's see how many minor variations on this exact same issue we can get posted here within a couple hours. Been at least 3 so far.

Comment: @squint At least it's not event delegation :p

Comment: why negative votes, can anyone please explain?

Comment: @suu It's not the most elegantly worded question, but I don't see why it deserves downvotes.  If people have issues they should tell you so you can fix them.  Some people are just mean.

Comment: @squint I have duped more than 2 of them. But I got bored of doing that and answered it here. :p

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy: Yeah, I saw both of those. You've done your part. ;-)

Comment: I even searched for duplicates, but couldn't find as 'click' word is not in the duplicate one . lol .

Comment: [site:stackoverflow.com javascript getelementsbyclassname addeventlistener doesn't work](https://www.google.com/search?num=50&q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+javascript+getelementsbyclassname+addeventlistener+doesn%27t+work&oq=site%3Astackoverflow.com+javascript+getelementsbyclassname+addeventlistener+doesn%27t+work)

Comment: @Archer: Doesn't take much research effort to find an answer to commonly asked questions like this. Hover your mouse pointer over the down arrow and you'll see it has *nothing* to do with being mean.

Comment: Yeah, it is.  There's a high level of anonymous vindictiveness on this site, and anyone who says they don't know that is actually ignoring it because they're doing it themselves.  Let's agree to disagree.

Comment: @Archer: 1) You're assuming they're being vindictive. 2) You're accusing anyone of disagreeing with you of being vindictive. 3) It's unreasonable to suggest that anyone would have reason to be "vindictive" against a user that has only made 3 posts here. Not much opportunity to offend. So no, I won't agree to anything with someone throwing blanket accusations around at other users.

Comment: Okay - cool story.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over *each* elements and `bind` event to that,

```
[].forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName('test'),function(elm){
 elm.addEventListener('click', function(){
  alert('Hello world');
 }, false);
});
```

Basically `getElementsByClassName` will return a `nodeList`. That means collection of node Object. node object has the function addEventListener in its prototype But not a nodeList.

Comment: What do you do when the elements are dynamically generated though?